# ctags can't recognize the constants in Ruby's module file

Tags: ruby, vim, ctags

I'm using ctags to generate the tag file for ruby. Looks like it can't recognize the constants defined in a module.

For example:

```
module Foo
     MAX_LEN = 15
end
```

Looks like the MAX_LEN will not be indexed. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> at `MAX_LEN` in VIM, it says `tag not found: MAX_LEN`.

Comment: There are a number of language-specific alternatives to Exuberant Ctags. Did you check [rdoc-tags](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc-tags)?

Answer (score 0):

The lattest Universal Ctags (https://ctags.io/) can extract constants.

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.rb 
module Foo
     MAX_LEN = 15
end
$ u-ctags -o - /tmp/foo.rb 
Foo /tmp/foo.rb /^module Foo$/;"    m
MAX_LEN /tmp/foo.rb /^     MAX_LEN = 15$/;" C   module:Foo
```